# How do I fix tailwindcss-cli from throwing TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function?

Tags: html, npm, tailwind-css, postcss

I've been following [Tailwind's tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYgogv4R8zg) and when. I get to the part of the tutorial where they ask me to run `npx tailwindcss-cli build css/tailwind.css -o build/tailwind.css`, I get the following error. How do I solve this?

```
(node:5568) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
/Users/USERNAME-REDACTED/.npm/_npx/8bcfa250e55e6bf5/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/jit/corePlugins.js:242
  ...Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(corePlugins).map(([pluginName, plugin]) => {
            ^

TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/USERNAME-REDACTED/.npm/_npx/8bcfa250e55e6bf5/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/jit/corePlugins.js:242:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/USERNAME-REDACTED/.npm/_npx/8bcfa250e55e6bf5/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/jit/lib/setupContextUtils.js:36:43)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
```

I've tried deleting npm, updating npm, removing my package-lock and node modules and restarting, and adding -i. all to no prevail. As is made apparent from the youtube series I linked, I'm just learning tailwind, so I'm sure it's a super stupid mistake.

Comment: Can you check the NodeJS version? Run `node --version` in console. The min. requirement is v12.13: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrading-to-v2#upgrade-to-node-js-12-13-or-higher

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue originated from your node version.
Please try this:

```
sudo npm i -g n
```

Than inside your project folder

```
n latest
```

after that close your current terminal, since it will remember the old node location, open a new one and it should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the overhead of nvm then you can just download a binary release of nodejs, eg:

> mkdir -p ~/opt/src
>
> cd ~/opt/src
>
> wget https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.17.0/node-v14.17.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
> cd ~/opt tar xf src/node-v14.17.0-linux-x64.tar.xz --strip 1

To use it interactively first run:

> export PATH=$HOME/opt/bin:$PATH

Source:https://community.opalstack.com/d/636-install-node-and-npm-without-having-to-sudo